# QString.sprintf() returns string withouth formating it

Tags: c++, printf, qstring

I've the odd situation that something (very rare) `QString.sprintf()` called with a simple `int` parameter doesn't seem to work for me:

```
QString debug_str;
if( doSomething )
{
    for( int i=5; i>0; --i )
    {
        LOG_INFO( debug_str.sprintf("remaining steps: %d\n", i ) );
    }
}
```

This is what I normally receive (many 100-of-thousand times):

```
remaining steps: 5
remaining steps: 4
remaining steps: 3
remaining steps: 2
remaining steps: 1
```

But at some point `QString.sprintf` stops formatting the string an returns:

```
remaining steps: 5
remaining steps: 4
remaining steps: %d
remaining steps: %d
remaining steps: %d
```

I've checked with the logger... it does receive this un-formatted string from the `sprintf` call. And from this point forward... this QString is broken for sprintf call.

Anyone an idea whats going an?

Comment: `LOG_INFO( debug_str.sprintf("remaining steps: %d\n", i) );` maybe?

Comment: You're missing the `i` parameter, and undefined behaviour ensues.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. :( Changed it.

Comment: Are you calling this function from multiple threads?

Comment: Yes, but ``QString debug_str`` is on the local thread stack. The ``QString`` instance is not shared between threads.

Comment: Well, either you've corrupted something in your program that is affecting QString, or QString is broken, or (even though you said there shouldn't be a threading issue), your hitting the same QString object simultaneously, causing a data race.